# Emacs - notify when a file has been modified externally

Tags: file-io, emacs, text-editor

How do I make emacs notify me about the fact that one or more visited files are changed from elsewhere? Here's how this functionality is implemented in Gedit:

[image: gedit - notify about external changes]

I've taken a look at the approaches explained in the ["Revert Buffer"](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RevertBuffer) document at EmacsWiki and found sort of a workaround (modified a bit for my personal preference):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda ()
  (interactive)
  (if (string= (buffer-name) ecb-directories-buffer-name)
    (refresh-ecb)
    (if (buffer-modified-p)
      (revert-buffer) ; ask for confirmation
      (revert-buffer t t))))) ; don't ask for confirmation - it's unnecessary, since the buffer hasn't been modified
```

That's great, but what I would like is to have an automatic solution. Maybe, some kind of noisy message inlined in a buffer (like in the screenshot). Maybe, even a modal dialog as implemented in Visual Studio (that's annoying, but it does the trick, after all). What would be your suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't emacs warn you with a question when a buffer is modified outside of emacs? Isn't that noisy enough?

Comment: Yeah, it does, but only when the buffer is not dirty and only when I start typing, but not immediately when I switch to the buffer.

Comment: Please update the image, if that's possible

Comment: Duh. That was me cleaning up my g+ account. Luckily I just made all the images private, but not deleted them. Therefore it was a simple permission fix. Does it work for you now?

Comment: The images are broken. S.O. lets you upload images, IIRC. Please use that facility, rather than an unreliable external host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've been able to come up with - big thanks to the guys from EmacsWiki for hints. I created a callback that gets triggered every few seconds - it checks modtime and displays an annoying message if the file has been modified.

On the upside, the solution mostly works and notifies me about changes regardless of whether the buffer is modified or not. On the downside, it involves constant polling of current file for modtime, but my work scenarios can tolerate that.

[image: emacs notify external changes]

```
;(global-auto-revert-mode 1)
(defun ask-user-about-supersession-threat (fn) "blatantly ignore files that changed on disk")
(run-with-timer 0 2 'my-check-external-modifications)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-check-external-modifications)
(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'my-check-external-modifications)

(defun my-load-external-modifications ()
  (interactive)
  (if (string= (buffer-name) ecb-directories-buffer-name)
    (refresh-ecb)
    (if (buffer-modified-p)
      (revert-buffer) ; ask for confirmation
      (revert-buffer t t)) ; don't ask for confirmation - it's unnecessary, since the buffer hasn't been modified
    (my-check-external-modifications))) 

(defun my-overwrite-external-modifications ()
  (interactive)
  (clear-visited-file-modtime)
  (set-buffer-modified-p (current-buffer))
  (save-buffer)
  (my-check-external-modifications))

(defun my-check-external-modifications ()
  (if (verify-visited-file-modtime (current-buffer))
    (progn
      (global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'my-load-external-modifications)
      (global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'save-buffer)
      (setq header-line-format tabbar-header-line-format))
    (progn
      (global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'my-load-external-modifications)
      (global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'my-overwrite-external-modifications)
      (setq header-line-format (format "%s. Press F5 to load external changes, C-s to overwrite them"
        (propertize "This file has been changed externally" 'face '(:foreground "#f00")))))))
```

Comment: You mentioned you read the wiki WRT reverting, but I thought I'd mention it here as well:  in many cases either auto-revert-mode or global-auto-revert-mode is a good solution.  That mode admits modification via the auto-revert-mode-interval and auto-revert-mode-hook variables.

I know you considered this approach, since your code sample has global-auto-revert-mode commented out at the top, but it might be useful for others.

Comment: that might be because my code has references to ECB that you might not have installed. also, there might be a discrepancy between your and mine emacs versions (mine is 23.2.1). finally, to debug stuff in emacs you have two options that I know of: 1) run emacs with --debug-init to debug errors in .emacs, 2) put (setq stack-trace-on-error t) or (setq debug-on-error t) somewhere in your .emacs to debug runtime errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the warning for dirty buffers too then you could advise switch-to-buffer, so when you switch to a buffer and it's modified then it would check if the file is modified and if so then it could offer to revert it like the built-in check does in case of unmodified buffers.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've searched for something like switch-to-buffer-hook, but without any luck. Creating an advice is definitely a way to go!